# Как сохранить WebSession Awesonium'a в c# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Вообщем, не знаю куда податься в оффДокументации ничего не нашел. Гугл подсказал только для WFA. Может тут кто-нибудь уже решал эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Собственно все оказалось довольно просто. Не знаю почему я вчера 4 часа над этим голову ломал.
webControl.WebSession = WebCore.CreateWebSession(Environment.CurrentDirectory, WebPreferences.Default);

Сохраняет он правда странно. Не всегда с первого раза(таймер там какой или что)